# UICollectionView defaulting to one column, how do I get two?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been learning about UICollectionViews recently and I am currently trying to implement one. I need to display two columns but no matter what I do it defaults to one column. There are plenty of similar questions here that suggest adjusting the width of the UICollectionView cell using the `collectionView` function `sizeForItemAt`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

[image: This is what it looks like right now. The collection view background is blue, and the cell backgrounds are red.]

this is my viewcontroller code:

```
class PreferencesViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.vertical
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.register(CategorySelectorCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "categorySelector")
    cv.backgroundColor = .clear
    return cv
}()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .blue
    collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height/1.5).isActive = true


    self.view = view
}
```

}

my delegate extension:

```
extension PreferencesViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "categorySelector", for: indexPath) as! CategorySelectorCell
    cell.cat = categories[indexPath.section]
    cell.backgroundColor = .red

    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
}
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    10
}
```

}

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Also add these `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
```

Update

Also set inset to zero

```
lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
       let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
       layout.sectionInset = .zero
       layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.vertical
       let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
       cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       cv.register(CategorySelectorCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "categorySelector")
       cv.backgroundColor = .clear
       return cv
   }()
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It made the width of the cells smaller as expected but they remained in one column.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but still not working. I added your functions as well. Could it have something to do with my custom cell class? It's just an imageView and a label as you can see.

Comment: No it wasn't, although I found a compromise. I believe it must have had something to do with the way I structured my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

let's think your collection view **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** has 16 edge insets starts and end. And **minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt**,**minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt** to 16

Then you can calculate your cell width like this

> (view.frame.width-flowlayoutInsets-sectionSpacing)/2

This is the codes

your collection view

```
let coll: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)
        let coll = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        coll.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        //other stuff
        return coll
    }()
```

Section and Line spacing

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 16
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 16
}
```

Collectionview cell size

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width-16-16-16)/2, height: 100)
        //1st 16 - left gap - flowlayout left inset
        //2nd 16 - middle gap - section spacing
        // 3rd 16 = right gap - flowlayout right inset
    }
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, so I think it must have been something on my end. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.